# React Native: Searchbar disappears after typing one single letter

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

In my React Native project, I want to create a searchable list as shown in [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-build-a-react-native-flatlist-with-realtime-searching-ability-81ad100f6699/) article.

Now when I copy and paste the code from [here](https://github.com/vikrantnegi/react-native-searchable-flatlist/blob/master/src/SearchableList.js), everything works fine.

But I must do some modifications to use it in my project. For example, I do not need to fetch random dummy data to fill the list but already have one, which is much structured much simpler. Furthermore, I want to use Function Component with Hooks instead of Class Component. (And I use Native Base instead of Native-Elements for the SearchBar, but this seems not to be any problem.)

So I converted the article's example as stated above into a Function Component, but now the SearchBar-Typing is broken.

The SearchBar now lets only type one single letter, then the keyboard disappears and you have to click the input field again to continue typing. I absolutely have no idea what I'm doing wrong here. I already tried to work with `useEffect()` Hook, without success. Can you help me?

Here is the animated problem:

[image]

And here is the code:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {View, FlatList, ActivityIndicator, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {Button, Header, Icon, Item, Input, Text} from 'native-base';

type Props = {};

const FlatListDemo: React.FC<Props> = ({}) => {
  const arrayholder = [
    {
      id: '1',
      name: 'Hopper',
      selected: false,
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      name: 'Dustin',
      selected: false,
    },
    {
      id: '3',
      name: 'Mike',
      selected: false,
    },
  ];
  const [data, setData] = useState(arrayholder);
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');

  renderSeparator = () => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          height: 1,
          width: '86%',
          backgroundColor: '#CED0CE',
          marginLeft: '14%',
        }}
      />
    );
  };

  const textChangedFunction = text => {
    setValue(text);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    searchFilterFunction(value);
  }, [value]);

  const searchFilterFunction = text => {
    setValue(text);

    const newData = arrayholder.filter(item => {
      const itemData = `${item.name.toUpperCase()}`;
      const textData = text.toUpperCase();

      return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
    });
    setData(newData);
  };

  renderHeader = () => {
    return (
      <Header searchBar rounded>
        <Item>
          <Icon name="ios-search" />
          <Input
            placeholder="Type Here..."
            onChangeText={text => textChangedFunction(text)}
            value={value}
          />
        </Item>
      </Header>
    );
  };

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        renderItem={({item}) => (
          <ListItem title={`${item.name}`} subtitle={item.id} />
        )}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={renderSeparator}
        ListHeaderComponent={renderHeader}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default FlatListDemo;
```

Help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Kindly change the Flatlist to this

```
{data.map((item, index) => {
    return  <Text style={ {padding: 10,}}>{item.name}</Text>;
})}
```